# Is there any way to auto translate an xml file?

Tags: java, xml, javafx, translate

I have a javafx program with lots of labels and buttons. The text on the labels and buttons are pulled from a very long xml file. Here is a small sample,

```
     <!-- PROGRAM ICON FILES -->
    <property name="NEW_BUTTON"         value="New"></property>
    <property name="LOAD_BUTTON"        value="Load"></property>
    <property name="SAVE_BUTTON"        value="Save"></property>
    <property name="SAVE_AS_BUTTON"     value="Save As"></property> 
    <property name="EXPORT_BUTTON"      value="Export"></property>
    <property name="EXIT_BUTTON"        value="Exit"></property> 
    <property name="REDO_BUTTON"        value="Redo"></property> 
    <property name="UNDO_BUTTON"        value="Undo"></property> 
    <property name="ABOUT_BUTTON"       value="About"></property>
```

I want to create a second xml file that is almost identical to the first one. Except in this second all the value strings will be replaced with a different language. That way when choosing a language, I just choose which xml file to load.

Is there a better way to replace all the values in my new xml file then just one by one copying them into Google Translate and replacing the original with the result.

Thanks

Comment: How would you expect that to work, exactly?

Comment: Sure.  There should be a tool to do that.  Look for a stand-alone tool that performs XSLT translations, and then design / implement a translation that does what you want.

Comment: Expect what to work? The two xml files or the auto translating? I know the two xml files work, i've tested it. As for the translating I have no idea, that why I'm was asking. It's definitely not impossible and someone could build a program that translates xml files. I'm asking to find out if such a thing exists.

Comment: I found this http://www.nikse.dk/XmlContentTranslator but it does not seem to work for my xml file

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 Solutions.

1) The Quicker and Less Expensive way: Take each value (text to be translated) and use google translate on Google. Simply have 2 tabs open. On the first tab, google: English to Spanish and on the second tab, google Spanish to English. (This way saved me 2,000 dollars from the second method).

2) The Lazy and More Expensive Way: In the Google Play Developer Console, Click on your app, then Services, you should see a translate button. Then, it will prompt you to add a strings.xml file. If you continue and agree, they will charge you $ to translate each value in your strings.xml to the desired languages. I'd go with the first method :)

Comment: How much text did you need to translate? $2000 is a lot given the prices Google Translate offers now. Thanks for sharing!